# How to get webpack file in django?

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, filepath, django-webpack-loader

I've made a webpack file(as `MainPage.js`) in output folder which I set up on `webpack.config.js` However, when I access to my `main page` it says there is no `MainPage.js`. What's wrong with it?? (I'm using Django on backend and React on frontend)

[image]

**Hierarchy of my folder**

```
Cebula4
    -  back
         - settings.py
         - manage.py
    -  front
         - webpack-stats.json
         - webpack.config.js
         - static
             - bundles
                  - MainPage.js (I checked that it was existed)
```

**Settings.py**

```
...

BASE_DIR = "C:\\Users\\1Sun\\Cebula4"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

...

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT' : {
            'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
            'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'front/webpack-stats.json'),

    }
}

...
```

Comment: that is a problem with your python server not serving files correctly. 
`STATIC_URL = '/static/bundles'` should fix

Comment: @PlayMa256 Thanks for your reply, but the error is still existed.. Request URL is changed to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bundles/bundles/MainPage.js`